# „Ich hätte“ oder „ich hatte“

Tags: verb, tense

I have translated both *hatte* and *hätte* and it says *would have.* Do these words have some differences? I have searched other questions and saw that the words really exist, initially my thought was that it was a typo.

So is it (The only instance where I come across this word is at a restaurant)

> Ich hätte gerne or ich hatte gerne?

I have also seen words like *konnen/könnten* (suppose both these words also mean the same, correct me if I am wrong).

So how does these words differ from each other?

Please give examples to explain the difference.

Comment: Please explain why a grammar book did not help you.

Comment: I translated the words to get the same meaning.

Comment: Let me emphasise ***grammar** book*.

Comment: I remember learning in my grammar classes where I had only hätte. It was explained as Would have. I was searching through something to to see another word hatte. then i remembered about könnte and konnte.

Comment: There is no German word "konnen". Is it a spelling mistake? Do you mean "konnten"?

Comment: i meant the infinitive form of kann, it is können i suppose.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was downvoted. It is totally valid and it is also a very common question in beginning German classes. Lastly, I do not see this as an off-topic question on this German language stackexchange sub-group.

Comment: Agreed.  This site is getting very heavy-handed in its closing of topics and downvoting, and it comes at the cost of restricting the number of useful keyword and phrasal entry paths to reach important topics via the search engines..  It definitely was not like this the first few years of its inception and therefore was more fun and more useful.  I have restricted my posting of questions a lot because of this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are different conjugations. Usually, verbs endind **-te** are written in their preterite form (past form). Umlauts **¨(ä, ö, ü)** are usually used for the conditional of the verb, and change the pronunciation of the vowel.

Present:

> I have = ich habe
>   I can = ich kann

Preterite:

> I had = ich hatte
>   I could = ich konnte

Conditional:

> I would have = Ich hätte
>   I (possibly) could = Ich könnte

In restaurants, it is usual to use the conditional to speak in a more polite way.

**Gern** means that you like or would like to do/have sth.

> Ich schwimme gern = I like to swim (present)
>   Ich hatte gern = I liked to have (preterite, because of hatte and not habe)
>   Ich hätte gern = I would like to have (conditional)

Comment: As an Addition: gerne/gern means also: with pleasure!

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Langauge Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. For questions on how it works, visit the [help]. Nice answer!